# Android access any common directory

Tags: android

I am beginner in app development.

I was trying various option found on internet to save a pdf file in memory through code.

For getting the Download folder,

First I tried

`downloadDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`

But it ended up in open failed EACCES permission denied error.

Then I tried

'downloadDirectory = contextwrapper.getDataDir();'  creates file but I couldn't locate it through file manager.

then

'downloadDirectory = contextwrapper.getObbDir();' created file in Internal memory/Android/obb/"App folder/

then

`ContextWrapper contextwrapper=new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()); downloadDirectory=contextwrapper.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`

But this save it in Android\data"App folder"\files\Downloads

Looks difficult for an ordinary user to access the folder.
Also obb folder and data folder both when opened file manager show a message on file manager saying "The contents of this folder will no longer be accessible due to system restrictions introduced in Android R. Remove your personal files from this folder as soon as possible."

Then where to save reports generated from my App?
Is there any method by which I can save this file in normal download folder or any other common folder easily accessible to ordinary user..

Please help...

Comment: Not clear if you read: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for a few things-

1. Check if `permission` is granted or not.
2. Check if you set `requestLegacyExternalStorage` to true in the manifest.

`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

3. Check for the method by which you're trying to save the pdf. `MediaStore Api` will be a good option to use.

Comment: By adding android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true", downloadDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS); I could access the Internal Storage/Download folder. Thank you

Comment: if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                downloadDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
               
            }
            else
            {
                
            }

Comment: Is this if condition needed?

Comment: Happy to help. Check the answer as Correct answer and an upvote is appriciated.

Comment: i tried it earlier itself but " Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: please check that if condition doubt in my comment. thank you..

Comment: It's better to have it because this is introduced from Android 11 or over. In this way you have more controls for different android versions.

Comment: Got it. I give you an upvote. Now you've access to the correct answer and upvote I hope.

Comment: `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) { downloadDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS); } else { } `

Comment: what to do in the else statement...

Comment: You can skip the if for now, it'll work without it.